# "C89/C99 say they're macros. Make them happy."?

Tags: c, macros, standards

I found this interesting code in `/usr/include/stdio.h` on various Linux systems I have access to.

```
167 /* Standard streams.  */
168 extern struct _IO_FILE *stdin;      /* Standard input stream.  */
169 extern struct _IO_FILE *stdout;     /* Standard output stream.  */
170 extern struct _IO_FILE *stderr;     /* Standard error output stream.  */
171 /* C89/C99 say they're macros.  Make them happy.  */
172 #define stdin stdin
173 #define stdout stdout
174 #define stderr stderr
```

[image: Screenshot]
Question: What's the point in defining a macro that does essentially nothing?

Comment: So you can use `#ifdef` for example

Comment: Probably because otherwise it wouldn't comply with the standard.

Comment: What part of the comment that you copied do you not understand?

Comment: So #undef stdin will work.

Comment: Why did you post the code twice

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The C11 defines `stdin`, `stdout` and `stderr` in [7.21.1p3](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#7.21.1p3):

> 3. The macros [defined in `<stdio.h>`] are
>
>    [...]
>
>    - `stderr`
>    - `stdin`
>    - `stdout`
>
>    which are expressions of type *pointer to `FILE`* that point to the `FILE` objects associated, respectively, with the standard error, input, and output streams.
>
>    [...]

Since the standard says these are macros, they must be macros. However the expressions must have some definition, and the standard *allows* them to *also* be used as variable names, but they don't have to be actual identifiers.

Linux userland tries to mostly conform to the POSIX standard in addition to conforming to the C11 standard. In POSIX, the requirement is that [these symbols are external identifiers](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/stdin.html). Since C11 requires that they be macros and POSIX requires that they're external identifiers, this is achieved easiest by defining a macro by the exact same name as the corresponding identifier.

It is indeed debatable if the POSIX standard *intends* them to *also* be variables with external linkage, but it is of note that [POSIX.1 2008 standard](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/) does state in its System Interfaces volume that

> The only sections relating to conformance are the SYNOPSIS, DESCRIPTION, RETURN VALUE, and ERRORS sections.

And the [SYNOPSIS section](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/stdin.html) for these does say that:

> **SYNOPSIS**
>
> ```
> #include <stdio.h>
>
> extern FILE *stderr, *stdin, *stdout;
> ```

Comment: I don't see any evidence for the claim that POSIX requires them to be external identifiers. The synopsis linked is just sloppy notation not a normative requirement.

Comment: @R.. now that I am reading the page I must disagree. The wording is distinct from `errno` for example; `errno` doesn't have any specific linkage in synopsis.

Comment: I still think it's just sloppy, not any conscious intent.

Comment: The most satisfactory part of the answer is your mentioning POSIX's requirements. Never have heard of that!